I can not make the ball stop oscillating
I am trying to do a basic ball and beam python simulation interface using TKinter, and for startes I just want the ball to oscillate a bit when it reaches the setpoint and I have attempted to do it, but it keeps on oscillating and oscillating and I don't know how to stop it (after its been moved by the slider)
This is my code please help :((
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def update_shapes(val):
    # Move the oval based on the scale value
    offset = int(val)
    C.coords(oval, 230 + offset, 45, 270 + offset, 85)
    
    # Start the return animation after a delay
    root.after(1500, return_to_origin)`your text`

def return_to_origin():
    # Animate the oval back to its original position
    current_coords = C.coords(oval)
    start_x = 230
    end_x = current_coords[0]  # Current x position
    step = 1 if end_x > start_x else -1

    if end_x != start_x:
        end_x -= step
        C.coords(oval, end_x, 45, end_x + 40, 85)
        root.update()
        root.after(10, return_to_origin)  # Call again after a short delay
    else:
        H.set(0)  # Reset the scale to zero
        #root.after(200, oscillate_first_back)  # Start the first oscillation segment after a delay
"""
def oscillate_first_back():
    # First half of first oscillation - go back
    for i in range(40):
        C.move(oval, -1, 0)
        root.update()
        root.after(10)
    root.after(10, oscillate_first_forward)  # Proceed to next phase

def oscillate_first_forward():
    # Second half of first oscillation - go forward
    for i in range(80):
        C.move(oval, 1, 0)
        root.update()
        root.after(10)
    root.after(10, oscillate_second_back)  # Proceed to next phase

def oscillate_second_back():
    # First half of second oscillation - go back
    for i in range(20):
        C.move(oval, -1, 0)
        root.update()
        root.after(10)
    root.after(10, oscillate_second_forward)  # Proceed to next phase

def oscillate_second_forward():
    # Second half of second oscillation - go forward
    for i in range(40):
        C.move(oval, 1, 0)
        root.update()
        root.after(10)
    root.after(10, reset_position)  # Proceed to final reset

def reset_position():
    # Reset the oval to the original position
    C.coords(oval, 230, 45, 270, 85)  # Center at original position
"""
# Create a horizontal scale
H = Scale(root, from_=-150, to=150, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=update_shapes)
H.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Create a canvas
C = Canvas(root, bg="#92dadd", height=230, width=500)

# Draw shapes
oval = C.create_oval(230, 45, 270, 85, fill="white", outline="")
line = C.create_line(100, 100, 400, 100, fill="black", width=22)
rectangle = C.create_rectangle(390, 75, 420, 220, fill="black")
motor = C.create_rectangle(100, 165, 115, 100, fill="black")

C.grid(row=1, column=0)
mainloop()


Please describe more exactly what to do to show the error and what should happen. I tried and I don't see any oscillation.

Note that a new after loop (executing return_to_origin()) will be created whenever update_shapes() is executed.  You need to cancel the current after loop before calling .after(...) inside update_shapes().  .after(...) should be executed only offset > 0 as well.

I copied your code and I only see an empty screen.

@ keventhen4. Are you using macos?
